# Has anybody used a proof assistant to prove soundness of a typed process calculus?

Tags: proof-system

...And have they published the results where I can afford to read them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, there is a proof of soundness for the process calculus underlying the Pict programming language in David N.Turner's thesis.

Answer (score 2):

There are several people doing things along those lines.  Look through the papers at John Rushbie's [PVS](http://pvs.csl.sri.com/) site, and look at [Coq's](http://coq.inria.fr/) papers.

Searching [Citeseer](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/) will probably do some good too — almost everyone nowadays publishes their preprints to Citeseer, so a little looking around will usually get you the same paper, or something very very similar to the paper published in the expensive journal.

Answer (score 1):

The [Archive of Formal Proofs](http://afp.sf.net) has several entries in the category "Process Calculi" listed in its [topics](http://afp.sourceforge.net/topics.shtml), such as CCS and Pi Calculus.